# Как спроектировать базу данных для многоязычного сайта?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Статьи должны находится в базе данных на трех языках.

Как примерно спроектировать базу данных нужно ли мне список поддерживаемых языков хранить в отдельной таблице, нужно ли использовать плагин(если да то какой ?) или обойтись возможностями  Laravel ?

Comment: Просто добавить поле language к таблице со статьёй да и всё, например

Comment: то есть одна таблица с language_ru, laguage_eu  ...  статьями ?

Comment: Для ларавел рекомендую этот пакет https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable

Comment: Поля в таблицы ТОЧНО добавлять не стоит. а вот отдельную табличку - вполне можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос довольно общий, поскольку мы не знаем, нужно ли в будущем предусмотреть добавление других языков и т.д.

Laravel из коробки предоставляет [локализацию](http://%20Laravel%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82) статичных данных, поэтому все статичные блоки можно реализовать с помощью неё.

Что касается динамичных данных, то для статей предлагаю следующую структуру:

- таблица языков
- таблица статей (тут вся информация, которая не подлежит переводу, т.е. id, created_at, rating и т.д.
- таблица контента. Сюда добавляете любые столбцы. К примеру: name, description, content. Редактору предоставляете доступ для написания статей на разных языках. При этом, само собой, таблица имеет поля `article_id` и `language_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Относительно локализации сайта нашел для себя универсальное решение.

- Таблица для языков. (Language)
- Таблица для доменов. (Domain) (К примеру для api, фронта и оплаты)
- Пишем сервис, который выдаёт нам список языков/локалей, всё это кэширует, инвалидирует кэш и тд.
- Пишем singleton в провайдере на получение списка языков/локалей (Используем сервис)
- Пишем middleware для локализации по локали из реквеста/заголовка (Locale)

В CRUD'е или в Observer'е прописываем логику инвалидации кэша и кэширования.

Можешь попробовать использовать следующие пакеты, уже использовал в других проектах, довольно простая реализация.

В отдельной таблице
https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable

В json'е
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable